# Where in Django can I run startup to load data?

Tags: python, django

I have a django application that loads a huge array into memory after django is started for further processing.

What I do now is , after loading a specific view, I execute the code to load the array as follows:

```
try:
    load_model = load_model_func()
except:
    #Some exception
```

The code is now very bad. I want to create a class to load this model once after starting django  and I want to be able to get this model in all other this model in all other methods of the application

So, is there a good practice for loading data into memory after Django starts?

Comment: What do you mean with "load data into memory"? Database information into memory when the project start to serve? What is the reason to do that and not with requests to database?

Comment: @GeancarloMurillo The reason is that it is a large matrix and is used in all requests in this application for data processing. If I use db, the response time will increase dramatically, so I need this matrix always in memory. After loading the model it does not undergo update

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/cache/

Answer (score 7):

@Ken4scholar 's answer is a good response in terms of "good practice for loading data AFTER Django starts". It doesn't really address storing/accessing it.

If your data doesn't expire/change unless you reload the application, then using cache as suggested in comments is redundant, and depending on the cache storage you use you might end up still pulling from some db, creating overhead.

You can simply store it in-memory, like you are already doing. Adding an extra class to the mix won't really add anything, a simple global variable could do.

Consider something like this:

```py
# my_app/heavy_model.py
data = None

def load_model():
    global data
    data = load_your_expensive_model()

def get_data():
  if data is None:
      raise Exception("Expensive model not loaded")
  return data
```

and in your config (you can [lean more about applications and config here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/applications/)):

```py
# my_app/app_config.py
from django.apps import AppConfig

from my_app.heavy_model import load_model

class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    # ...
    def ready(self):
        load_model()
```

then you can simply call `my_app.heavy_model.get_data` directly in your views.

⚠️ You can also access the global `data` variable directly, but a wrapper around it may be nicer to have (also in case you want to create more abstractions around it later).

Comment: This design wouldn’t reload at every GET or POST request right? The model would be in memory already for any inbound API requests, right?

Comment: @jbuddy_13 that is correct! You may also want to read the notes here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.ready about some caveats on when `ready()` is run in tests.

Comment: How can I reload the data further down the road? Triggered, for example, by a new .csv file which contains the data been available?

Answer (score 3):

You can run a startup script when apps are initialized. To do this, call the script in  the ready method of your Config class in apps.py like this:

```
class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'myapp'

    def ready(self):
        <import and run script>
```